# Prime factorization using GUI (swing/awt)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jtextarea

This code uses Swing and awt to compute prime factorization, the code works, but it shows only one prime factor, for example: if i compute 56 the answer is just 7, how can i fix it?
thanks in advance

```
        calculate6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Get values from text fields
            try {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText());
                result.setText(String.valueOf(a + " "));
                for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {
                    while (a % i == 0) {
                        result.setText(String.valueOf(i + " "));
                //        System.out.println(i + " ");
                        a = a / i;
                    }
                }
                if (a < 1)                     
                    result.setText(String.valueOf(a + " "));
                //        System.out.println(a + " ");

            }
                catch (Exception f) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERROR: " + (f.getMessage()));
            }

            String aField = input1.getText(); 
            if (e.getSource() == calculate6) {
                if ("".equals(aField)) {
                    String emptyFieldWarning;
                    emptyFieldWarning = "One field is empty!";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, emptyFieldWarning);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit 1: i have changed the operation part

Answer (score 0):

Your Swing part is fine. If you just try to execute

```
 int a = 56;
    for(int i = 2; i< a; i++) {
        while (a % i == 0) {
            a = a / i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(a);
```

you get 7,so the problem is in this part, you shoul look over here

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the `while` loop. It is not accumulating the factors. Try this `getPrimeFactors()` in this sample program.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrimeFactors {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("56 -> " + PrimeFactors.getPrimeFactors(56));
    System.out.println("30 -> " + PrimeFactors.getPrimeFactors(30));
    System.out.println("154 -> " + PrimeFactors.getPrimeFactors(154));
  }

  public static List<Integer> getPrimeFactors(int input) {
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= input; i++) {
      while (input%i == 0) {
        input = input/i;
        factors.add(i);
      }
    }
    return factors;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried, but still getting the same values

Comment: Did you run this program I gave in the solution? It works for me.

Comment: Yes, now is running but is still showing the last value, is i add System.out.println(...) in the console i see all the values, but in the JTextField i see the last value

Comment: Are you setting the value to text field by `result.setText((result1));`? I guess you can use the value you are using for `System.out.println()` in `setText()` also.

Comment: i have changed my code, but is stil showing the last value (System.out.println() is for testing purpose)

Comment: Please add your UI code to the question. Then we might be able to point out the problem.

Comment: I've added the UI part

Comment: But you have not updated `calculate6.addActionListener()` part with my suggestions. May be you can post the whole code. Then we can run it and see the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i solved my problem using: result.setText(result.getText() + String.valueOf(a + " "));

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final IntFunction<String> getPrimeFactorsAsString = num -> {
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 2, sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(num); i <= sqrt; i++) {
        while (num % i == 0) {
            res.add(i);
            num /= i;
        }
    }

    return res.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
};
```

---

#### Demo

```
System.out.println(getPrimeFactorsAsString.apply(56));  // 2 2 2 7
System.out.println(getPrimeFactorsAsString.apply(660)); // 2 2 3 5 11
```